# Bounded $L^p$ functions

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

It is well known that we do not have $L^q(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $q >p$. But is this relation true, if we assume that we only look at bounded functions $f$. I think it could be right, because I could not find any counterexample for this situation so far. What do you think?

Comment: For any $p < q < r$, if $f \in L^p \cap L^r$, does that imply $f \in L^q$?

Comment: $r = \infty$ is one special case. The answer is indeed yes. Do you know how to prove that?

Comment: Actually, no. my first ideas would be about using Hölder's inequality and some kind of sandwich theorem consideration, where you get a lower and an upper bound for the integral. Do you think any of this could help? Otherwise, I would love to get another tip.

Comment: You can have it simpler. For $s < \infty$, remember that $f \in L^s$ if and only if $f$ is measurable, and $\lvert f\rvert^s \in L^1$.

Comment: ah sure, $\int |f|^q \le  C \int |f|^p $ does it.

Comment: @DanielFischer you are a great help.

Comment: I meant $\lvert f\rvert^q \leqslant \lvert f\rvert^p + \lvert f\rvert^r$. For $r = \infty$, you need a different estimate, $\lvert f\rvert^q \leqslant \lVert f\rVert_\infty^{q-p}\cdot \lvert f\rvert^p$ does the job.

Comment: Yep, that is my C

Comment: Ah, you were on the $r = \infty$ case.